# "To Put the flag up the pole and see who salutes"

Tags: idioms

1. Is this a common expression?
2. Is it used in an ironic way nowadays?
3. If the latter is the case: Is there a similar phrase that is usually not used ironically?

Comment: You have [plenty of options](http://dilbert.com/strip/2002-05-05).

Comment: I've generally heard "Run it up the flagpole and see who salutes."  I wouldn't say it's "common", but it's used.  As to "ironic", that's up to context and interpretation.

Comment: Used humorously [from c. 1960](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCEE9pOkvQU#t=549), so it had become something of a cliché to be lampooned, and has been used ironically since at least that time.

Comment: I actually think this term originated from advertising-speak in the 1950s, referring to the process of getting buy-in on ideas presented to clients.

Comment: Let's release a *beta*!

Answer (score -1):

i believe it is no longer fashionable. A similar phrase would be "to send up a trial balloon."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_it_up_the_flagpole

it is the first time i come across it and i liked it.thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Can you do us the courtesy of using proper punctuation in your postings?  Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thank you ma'am for reminding me. It is just my online habit I am afraid. I must also say I'm not in this good English language community to offend anybody--- I have been all my life always courteous to all people regardless of their faith, color, nationality, language or race.I totally agree with what that great American novelist Mark Twain once wrote "travel is fatal to prejudice, bigotry and narrow-mindedness.Broad,wholesome, charitable views of men and things cannot be acquired by vegetating in one little corner of the earth all one's lifetime".English is my second language.Let us be kind!

Comment: All good advice and I have to say that I can't throw a rock without hitting someone near me for whom English is a 2nd language or was raised by someone for whom English was a 2nd language - myself included.  I'm glad you're on the site and hope you come to love it as much as I do! :-)

Comment: +1 for such a commendable response. You're a beautiful soul, Sojourner, it has been said, "Strange travel suggestions are dancing lessons from God."

Comment: @LittleEva Thank you for your kind support! generous people like you is what make green, beautiful America great.As of MC and other related autoimmune didorders these ingenious guys http://mpkb.org/ seem to have"stumbled on" into a treatment! check them out.